# Chrome [Version 36.0.1985.125 m] missing 'Emulate Touch Screen' sensor for mobile emulation?

Tags: google-chrome, mobile

The checkbox is gone. Did they move it again?

In recent versions you could find "Emulate Touch" in the Emulation->Sensors dev tools area.

Note I am aiming to emulate iPhone 5.

Comment: See answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24836549/emulate-touch-screen-option-absent-device-emulation-provides-no-touch-screen-re

Comment: That seems reasonable since I'm using Win8, however I do not have a service called "Tablet PC Input Service". I do have "Touch Keyboard and Handwriting Panel Service" -- no good after stopping whatever service that is and restarting Chrome. Still no "Emulate Touch" available in settings.

Comment: After talking to a chrome dev on twitter he posted in that stackoverflow question a good workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this discussion http://t.co/GTK2jzUX4m it appears that there is a bug where Chrome will not give the option "Emulate Touch" if you are on a "device" that it believes is touch-enabled. So, I haven't fully tested this, but my guess is that this version of Chrome doesn't support Emulate Touch in Windows 8 since it supports touch natively, even if your hardware/device does not. Fix is coming, I guess.