# Unable to open select using Chrome devtools mobile mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, drop-down-menu, google-chrome-devtools

I created one file `test.html`:

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<style type="text/css">
select {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 120px;
}
</style>
```

And when using DevTools <kbd>F12</kbd> (any device display mode) it is blocking the select.

I also tried the `chrome://flags/#touch-events` option from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24935545/6188402).

Is there anything I can do to open the select in mobile mode using Chrome?

My Chrome version is `53.0.2785.116 m`.

**EDIT**

My chrome updated today to version `53.0.2785.143 m`.

And now the select shows up this way:

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem since I upgraded. I reported the issue yesterday, but in the meantime I'm going to downgrade chrome again, nothing more we can do I guess

Comment: Turns out you can't downgrade chrome because it automatically updates, using jquery now to change the values manually until it gets fixed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=645478). You can star the report to show it is affecting you and if you can please provide your OS and hardware configuration so the team can have as much information as possible from multiple people seeing this to figure out what is wrong.

Sadly, until the bug is fixed Device Mode can't be used to test select elements.

Thank you.

Comment: It works now in version 54 !! ... There is still a minor bug when you change from `100%` to other resolution, the options are not being resized (they remain their width equal to the select in 100% mode)... But I think we can live with that :)